# Why does loading a codeigniter view using ajax corrupts the css and js functions

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

So I have a main page named index.php, this contains the whole html page and the css and js assets as well.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/main.css';?>">
         <!-- this contains my other css -->
    <head>

    <body>
          <div id="wrapper">
               <div class="main-section">
                     <?= $home ?>
                     <!-- this is the section i want to replace using ajax --> 
                     <!-- $home is a codeigniter view of the section for home -->
               </div>
          </div>


    <script>
        var BASE = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.js';?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js';?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- other js files -->

    </body>

</html>
```

so when it is loaded like that, everything works fine. but when i use ajax function to change the content of main section like this,

```
JQ("#btnshop").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    JQ.ajax({
        url: BASE + "bhs/main/shop",
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
            $(".bhs-main-section").empty().html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the code of the controller i'm getting my content

```
public function shop()
{
    $data['tenants'] = $this->tenant->getTenants();
    $data['tenants_categories'] = $this->tenant_category->find(1);

    $this->load->view('bhs/shop', $data);
}
```

Any ideas why some of the css, and js are breaking? Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure your view doesn't have any css/html attached

Comment: check the answer you forgot to echo the content

Comment: it does.. any alternate way to load it in there? thanks anyway..

Comment: @NishantNair, i tried echoing it already, it displays the html but some of the css and js are not functioning correctly

Comment: Check for basepath in your external js and css, try to open the same path in browser, you will come to know that it is working or not.

Comment: Which js is not working imported in index? or written in view you are loading through ajax?

Comment: the view I'm importing has no js and css, its all present in the index page, the view is only the section.. I'm starting to think it has something to do with the sass..

Comment: do you get any errors in the `shop()` function?

Comment: that's the weird part, because it does not throw any errors..

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will never load the view

you need to echo the content in controller instead of loading view

```
public function shop()
{
$data['tenants'] = $this->tenant->getTenants();
$data['tenants_categories'] = $this->tenant_category->find(1);

$echo $this->load->view('bhs/shop', $data);
}
```

Comment: i tried to this as well, but same result, it loads the view, but the 'some css and js' does not function properly.

Comment: try to inspect and check the base path.

Answer (score 0):

when your view content ge that time you give third parameter in $

$this->load->view('view name',$data,true);

true mean retrun content.

```
public function shop()
    {
        $data['tenants'] = $this->tenant->getTenants();
        $data['tenants_categories'] = $this->tenant_category->find(1);

       $content= $this->load->view('bhs/shop', $data,TRUE);

    echo $content;

    }
```